# Using SQL-distinct function in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I want to create a list (MyList), where I get only one row for each IDNumber and the PersonName from an SQL-table (TABLE01). How is this written in LINQ. With the code below I get "Specified method is not supported"-

```
var MyList = (from a in TABLE01
              where a.IDNumber != " "
              select new
              {
                  Num = a.IDNumber.Distinct(),
                  Name = a.PersonName
              }).ToList();
```

**FULL STACK TRACE for Jon:

```
    at     Devart.Data.Linq.LinqCommandExecutionException.CanThrowLinqCommandExecutionException(String message, Exception e) at Devart.Data.Linq.Provider.DataProvider.ExecuteQuery(CompiledQuery compiledQuery, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, Object lastResult)    
at Devart.Data.Linq.Provider.DataProvider.ExecuteAllQueries(CompiledQuery compiledQuery, Object[] userArguments)
   at Devart.Data.Linq.Provider.DataProvider.CompiledQuery.Devart.Data.Linq.Provider.ICompiledQuery.Execute(IProvider provider, Object[] userArgs)
  at Devart.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.i()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Form1.Create_Modelist() in D:\projects\Form1.cs:line 488
at Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\projects\Form1.cs:line 565
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
at System.Windows.Forms.SafeNativeMethods.ShowWindow(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible(Boolean value)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
at .Program.Main() in D:\projects\Program.cs:line 18
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Are you trying to be distinct by IDNumber *and* PersonName, or just one of them? It's unclear from your question.

Comment: Sorry. Distinct by IDNumber.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that it's treating `IDNumber` as an `IEnumerable<char>` (because `string` is indeed a sequence of characters). You probably want something more like:

```
var list = (from a in TABLE01
            where a.IDNumber != " "
            group a.Name by a.IDNumber into g
            select new { Num = g.Key, Name = g.First() }).ToList();
```

This basically groups by IDNumber (so that you'll only get one group per number) and then takes the "first" (i.e. some arbitrary) name from the each group.

Comment: @KasperØstergaardSixhøj: I strongly suspect the error has more information than that.

Comment: @KasperØstergaardSixhøj: I still suspect there's more information than that - please edit the full stack trace, including any inner exceptions and messages, into your question (specifying that it's the result of trying my answer).

Comment: @KasperØstergaardSixhøj: Well, you've removed the type and the message from it, which doesn't help. Still, it tells us which LINQ provider you're using, which wasn't clear before. At this point, apart from anything else, I suggest you try writing a *tiny* console app which contains nothing but this code and whatever is required to initialize the database connection. That will make for *much* smaller stack traces...

Comment: I'll give it a shot Jon. Thanks so far! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the *a single* name for each ID, use Jon's answer.  If you wanted distinct ID/Names together then put distinct on the list rather than an individual property.

```
var MyList = (from a in TABLE01
                    where a.IDNumber != " "
                    select new
                               {
                                   Num = a.IDNumber,
                                   Name = a.PersonName
                               }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: That makes the combination of IDNumber and PersonName distinct. As he put the distinct only on IDNumber it might be that he only wants that distinct in which case group is required.

Comment: @AndyNichols Good point.  Looks like Jon has already covered that scenario with grouping.

Comment: I have a list of 27 million rows in which there are several rows with the same ID and Names in them. I just want a single row for each ID number with a name (First is ok. Last would be the best, based on the rownumber)...